# Npm run build cannot find required file?

Tags: reactjs

this is my error,

[image]

I've tried uninstall node modules and installing, and no fix yet.

Comment: Please post your code here too.

Comment: Which code is necessary to post?

Comment: Your index.html at least, To know which file is missing.

Comment: Where do you place your index.html?

Comment: Does my answer help? @julz oh?

Comment: It exists in a different folder but I don't understand why it's looking in that directory

Answer (score 0):

**So the error basically means that node was looking for `index.html` file in your `public` folder but it can't find one**

You will need to check if you properly place your `index.html` in your `public` folder or find it and move it to the `public` folder.

The file should be in `dev-connector/public/index.html`

---

**Or if you want to have your index.html in another folder, then you will need to change your [webpack.config](https://webpack.js.org/guides/output-management/)**

Something like this:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
    template: "./src/client/public/index.html",
    filename: "./index.html"
  })
];
```

Comment: It exists in client/public/index.html

Comment: No, it needs to be direct `dev-connector/public/index.html` not under `client` folder. If you want to move your `index.html` then change configure in your webpack.config.js